# ListView listener not intercepting events from item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, checkedtextview

I have a `ListView`:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/sensorList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chooseHint"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
</ListView>
```

Which has `CheckedTextView`s in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple" />
```

I have added an `OnItemClickListener` to do something when a list item is clicked. But also when an item is clicked, the checkbox is toggled. How can i achieve that the listener is catching the click event, but the checkbox is not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the `CheckedTextView` from toggling, do the following:
1. Subclass `CheckedTextView`.
2. Override `setChecked(boolean)` method.
3. Replace your `CheckedTextView` with the overridden one.

Code for steps 1 and 2:

```
package com.example.multichoicelist;
public class UnresponsiveCheckedTextView extends CheckedTextView {

    public UnresponsiveCheckedTextView(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
    }

    public UnresponsiveCheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
         this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public UnresponsiveCheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
              //Do nothing.
    }

}
```

It is the `setChecked` method that refreshes the checked state of the `CheckedTextView` which brings about the toggle effect. Overriding `setChecked` will prevent the checkbox of the `CheckedTextView` from getting toggled when the user clicks a list item.

XML for step 3:

```
<com.example.multichoicelist.UnresponsiveCheckedTextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
 />
```

Below is the activity containing a multiple choice `ListView` with an `OnItemClickListener` that shows the list item that has been clicked. Notice that during such a click event the checkbox **is not toggled** (thanks to the overridden `CheckedTextView` implementation):

```
package com.example.multichoicelist;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView mListView = getListView();
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        mListView.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.phonetic_alphabet, R.layout.list_item));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View childView,
            int adapterPosition, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                ((CheckedTextView) childView).getText() + " selected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The image below shows the behavior of the multiple choice `ListView` when the list item named 'Charlie' is clicked:

[image]